# Removing data from previous dates

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro with a reset button to delete all entries based on user id entered. Here is my code.

```
    Sub FlushData()

    Dim confirm As Variant

    confirm = InputBox("Enter your user ID for confirmation of erasing data.")

    If confirm = Environ("username") Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Booked").Range("A2:K100000").ClearContents

    Msgbox ("Previous entries erased.")

    Else

    Msgbox ("No user found.")

    End if

    End sub
```

Now, instead of entering user id, I want to automatically delete previous dates' entries every time the user clicks the reset button.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the entries cleared as soon as the button is clicked, you just need:

```
Sub FlushDataNoCheck()
      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets("Booked").Range("A2:K100000").ClearContents
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you'd like to keep a check in there to ensure the user hasn't accidentally hit the button, you can use the following:

```
Sub FlushDataWithCheck()

    Dim confirm As Variant
    
    confirm = MsgBox("Are you sure? Press OK to clear.", vbOKCancel, "Clear entries")
    
    If confirm = vbOK Then
    
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
        Sheets("Booked").Range("A2:K100000").ClearContents
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        MsgBox ("Previous entries erased.")
    
    Else
    
        MsgBox ("User cancelled request.")
    
    End If

End Sub
```

---

Here is a sub that deletes rows from a table, based on a given date (in your case today) and a column containing dates:

```
Sub DeleteRowsPriorToDate(dt As Date, strDateCol As String)

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim y As Long
    
    With Sheets("Booked")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, strDateCol).End(xlUp).Row
        For y = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            If .Range(strDateCol & y) < Int(dt) Then
                .Range(strDateCol & y).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

So add the code above and then instead of using this in the above code:

```
Sheets("Booked").Range("A2:K100000").ClearContents
```

use:

```
DeleteRowsPriorToDate Date,"C"
```

Or if you wanted just today and yesterdays..

```
DeleteRowsPriorToDate Date - 1,"C"
```

**Obviously, change "C" to the column that contains the dates.**

Comment: Thank you so much. what if I want to clear entries from previous dates only, and retain entries dated today?

Comment: Would today's entries all be at the bottom in one contiguous group, or scattered throughout the table?

Comment: the dates are automatically filled out once entries are added and the date column is fixed across all sheets.

Comment: I've added to my answer and given you a separate Sub which will delete based on a date in a given column.